# Start CDI Asynchronous bean and update Wicket UI with WebSockets

Tags: java, asynchronous, websocket, wicket, cdi

I have a WebApp with Wicket UI, where I'm trying to start a background job, so I inject an asynchronous bean (don't want the UI to block). To update my status when the bean finishes I push the message to the UI with WebSockets.

Bean code snippet for message push:

```
@Stateful
@RequestScoped
@Asynchronous
public class MyBeanAsync implements IMyBeanAsync{
    public void pushMessage(IWorkflowListener listener){
        try {
            LOG.info("CDI Async bean with message start @ "+ new java.util.Date());
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            LOG.info("CDI Async bean with message end @ "+ new java.util.Date());
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        listener.onMessage("CDI Message from bean @ "+ new java.util.Date());
    }
}
```

The problem is that I'm getting the following error when the message should show up in the UI:

```
ERROR [org.apache.wicket.protocol.ws.api.AbstractWebSocketProcessor] An error occurred during processing of a WebSocket message: javax.enterprise.context.ContextNotActiveException: Conversation Context 
not active when method called on conversation Transient conversation
 at org.jboss.weld.context.conversation.ConversationImpl.verifyConversationContextActive(ConversationImpl.java:192) [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]
 at org.jboss.weld.context.conversation.ConversationImpl.touch(ConversationImpl.java:153) [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]
 at org.jboss.weld.context.conversation.ConversationImpl.<init>(ConversationImpl.java:56) [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]
 at org.jboss.weld.bean.builtin.ConversationBean.newInstance(ConversationBean.java:39) [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]
 at org.jboss.weld.bean.builtin.ConversationBean.newInstance(ConversationBean.java:16) [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]
 at org.jboss.weld.bean.builtin.AbstractDecorableBuiltInBean.create(AbstractDecorableBuiltInBean.java:52) [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]
 at org.jboss.weld.context.AbstractContext.get(AbstractContext.java:96) [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]
 at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ContextBeanInstance.getInstance(ContextBeanInstance.java:98) [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]
 at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyMethodHandler.invoke(ProxyMethodHandler.java:99) [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]
 at org.jboss.weld.proxies.Conversation$1941972913$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.isTransient(Unknown Source)
 at org.apache.wicket.cdi.ConversationPropagator.onRequestHandlerScheduled(ConversationPropagator.java:130)
 at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycleListenerCollection$7.notify(RequestCycleListenerCollection.java:182)
 at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycleListenerCollection$7.notify(RequestCycleListenerCollection.java:178)
 at org.apache.wicket.util.listener.ListenerCollection.notify(ListenerCollection.java:80)
 at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycleListenerCollection.onRequestHandlerScheduled(RequestCycleListenerCollection.java:177)
 at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycleListenerCollection$7.notify(RequestCycleListenerCollection.java:182)
 at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycleListenerCollection$7.notify(RequestCycleListenerCollection.java:178)
 at org.apache.wicket.util.listener.ListenerCollection.notify(ListenerCollection.java:80)
 at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycleListenerCollection.onRequestHandlerScheduled(RequestCycleListenerCollection.java:177)
 at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycleListenerCollection$7.notify(RequestCycleListenerCollection.java:182)
 at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycleListenerCollection$7.notify(RequestCycleListenerCollection.java:178)
 at org.apache.wicket.util.listener.ListenerCollection.notify(ListenerCollection.java:80)
 at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycleListenerCollection.onRequestHandlerScheduled(RequestCycleListenerCollection.java:177)
 at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.scheduleRequestHandlerAfterCurrent(RequestCycle.java:766)
 at org.apache.wicket.protocol.ws.api.AbstractWebSocketProcessor.broadcastMessage(AbstractWebSocketProcessor.java:218)
 at org.apache.wicket.protocol.ws.api.AbstractWebSocketConnection.sendMessage(AbstractWebSocketConnection.java:43)
 at org.amadeus.inj.WorkflowListener.onMessage(WorkflowListener.java:48)
 at org.amadeus.inj.MyBeanAsync.pushMessage(MyBeanAsync.java:37) [Inj3-ejb.jar:]
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_65]
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_65]
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_65]
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) [rt.jar:1.7.0_65]
 at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.java:52)
 at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
 at org.jboss.invocation.WeavedInterceptor.processInvocation(WeavedInterceptor.java:53)
 at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:63)
 at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
 at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:407)
 at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.doMethodInterception(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:82) [wildfly-weld-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]
 at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.processInvocation(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:93) [wildfly-weld-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]
 at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:63)
 at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
 at org.jboss.invocation.WeavedInterceptor.processInvocation(WeavedInterceptor.java:53)
 at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:63)
 at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
 at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.ExecutionTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(ExecutionTimeInterceptor.java:43) [wildfly-ejb3-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]
 at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
 at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.SBInvocationInterceptor.processInvocation(SBInvocationInterceptor.java:47)
 at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
 at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.SFSBInvocationInterceptor.processInvocation(SFSBInvocationInterceptor.java:57)
 at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
 at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.stateful.StatefulSessionSynchronizationInterceptor.processInvocation(StatefulSessionSynchronizationInterceptor.java:127) [wildfly-ejb3-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]
 at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
 at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:407)
 at org.jboss.weld.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:55) [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]
 at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.processInvocation(EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:83) [wildfly-weld-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]
 at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
 at org.jboss.as.ee.concurrent.ConcurrentContextInterceptor.processInvocation(ConcurrentContextInterceptor.java:45) [wildfly-ee-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]
 at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
 at org.jboss.invocation.InitialInterceptor.processInvocation(InitialInterceptor.java:21)
 at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
 at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)
 at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.processInvocation(ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.java:53)
 at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
 at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.stateful.StatefulComponentInstanceInterceptor.processInvocation(StatefulComponentInstanceInterceptor.java:66) [wildfly-ejb3-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]
 at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
 at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:273) [wildfly-ejb3-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]
 at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.required(CMTTxInterceptor.java:340) [wildfly-ejb3-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]
 at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.processInvocation(CMTTxInterceptor.java:239) [wildfly-ejb3-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]
 at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
 at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:41) [wildfly-ejb3-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]
 at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
 at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.WaitTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(WaitTimeInterceptor.java:43) [wildfly-ejb3-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]
 at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
 at org.jboss.as.ejb3.security.SecurityContextInterceptor.processInvocation(SecurityContextInterceptor.java:95) [wildfly-ejb3-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]
 at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
 at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.ShutDownInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(ShutDownInterceptorFactory.java:64) [wildfly-ejb3-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]
 at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
 at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.LoggingInterceptor.processInvocation(LoggingInterceptor.java:59) [wildfly-ejb3-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]
 at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
 at org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50)
 at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
 at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AdditionalSetupInterceptor.processInvocation(AdditionalSetupInterceptor.java:55) [wildfly-ejb3-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]
 at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
 at org.jboss.invocation.ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.processInvocation(ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.java:64)
 at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
 at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.run(InterceptorContext.java:326)
 at org.wildfly.security.manager.WildFlySecurityManager.doChecked(WildFlySecurityManager.java:448)
 at org.jboss.invocation.AccessCheckingInterceptor.processInvocation(AccessCheckingInterceptor.java:61)
 at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
 at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.run(InterceptorContext.java:326)
 at org.jboss.invocation.PrivilegedWithCombinerInterceptor.processInvocation(PrivilegedWithCombinerInterceptor.java:80)
 at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
 at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)
 at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewService$View.invoke(ViewService.java:185)
 at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewDescription$1.processInvocation(ViewDescription.java:182)
 at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
 at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.LogDiagnosticContextRecoveryInterceptor.processInvocation(LogDiagnosticContextRecoveryInterceptor.java:79) [wildfly-ejb3-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]
 at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
 at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AsyncFutureInterceptorFactory$1$2.runInvocation(AsyncFutureInterceptorFactory.java:97) [wildfly-ejb3-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]
 at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AsyncInvocationTask.run(AsyncInvocationTask.java:73) [wildfly-ejb3-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_65]
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_65]
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_65]
 at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122)
```

Using WildFly 8.1.0.Final, Weld CDI 1.1, Java 1.7.

Repository: https://github.com/claudiu-stanciu/WicketCDI_Test/tree/AsyncCDI

Tried to recreate the context inside the bean with DeltaSpike, then call listener.onMessage() -> nothing.
Tried to use a runnable.run() with ExecutorService instead of Asynchronous and then call WebSockets onMessage -> ContextNotActiveException.

Some help would be welcome.

Comment: There is no active request scope for a websocket message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like http://wicket.apache.org/guide/guide/nativewebsockets.html#nativewebsockets_6 (the FAQ).
WebSocket communication is not intercepted by Servlet Filters so DI frameworks like CDI, Spring and Guice have no chance to prepare their scoped beans. In your case RequestScoped.
You can use only application and prototype scoped beans.

Comment: Thank you.I tried with @ApplicationScoped instead -> same response. Is there another way to get a feedback in the UI once the job is done?

Comment: Using CDI in Wicket comes for free when injecting in Component, Behavior, Session or Application. When you need to inject in a custom class you'll need to use NonContextual.of(...). The best resource for Wicket+CDI can be found at: https://www.42lines.net/tag/cdi/

Answer (score 0):

Clean solution: EJB instead of CDI. EJB @Asynchronous works with WebSockets.

Add the following line in init() of WebApplication extended class:

```
getComponentInstantiationListeners().add(new JavaEEComponentInjector(this));
```

Inject EJB in WebPage extended class:

```
@EJB(name="ejb/MyEJB")    // EJB ref name as defined in web.xml
    private IMyEJB myEJB; // EJB interface
```

Insert in web.xml (or would get a weird persistence error in WildFly)

```
    <ejb-local-ref>
        <ejb-ref-name>ejb/MyEJB</ejb-ref-name> <!-- Name of EJB bean -->
        <ejb-ref-type>Session</ejb-ref-type> 
        <local>org.amadeus.inj.IMyEJB</local> <!-- Qualified name of EJB bean -->
    </ejb-local-ref>
</web-app>
```

And dependencies for WicketStuff-JavaEE-Inject (http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.wicketstuff/wicketstuff-javaee-inject)

Repository quickstart https://github.com/claudiu-stanciu/WicketCDI_Test/tree/EJB_test